# jquery ajax call to check data from database always return an error - .NET

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am developping a functionality whereby users can check if an email already exist in the database( on a registration page ).

Basically for testing purposes, i have added a user with email address 'test@yopmail.com' in the database manually.

I am trying to check via ajax if this email exist. Here are the codes i am using:

```
    [WebMethod(MessageName = "CheckEmailAvailability", Description = "Check whether an Email is available.")]
    public string CheckEmailAvailability(string email)
    {
        var checkEmailAvailabilityResult = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            var membershipUser = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(email);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(membershipUser))
            {
                checkEmailAvailabilityResult = "EMAIL_ALREADY_EXIST";
            }
            else
            {
                checkEmailAvailabilityResult = "EMAIL_NOT_EXIST";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            checkEmailAvailabilityResult = "UNEXPECTED_ERROR";
        }

        return checkEmailAvailabilityResult;
    }

    #endregion
```

My ajax is:

```
  $('#test_json').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://locahost/WebServices/Email_Availability/Email_Availability_V1_1.asmx/CheckEmailAvailability",
    data: { email: JSON.stringify('test@yopmail.com')},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        alert('data');

    },
     error: function(data){ alert('Test'+data); }
  });
 });
```

The following is being alerted: Test[object]

What i am i doing wrong? please help

Comment: The error handler doesn't really return data, it has three arguments related to the error, read the docs. Console log those three arguments and tell us what they say, as you're clearly hitting the error handler.

Comment: Server side script error or network error, check your network tab

Comment: i get the following in my net panel:  OPTIONS CheckEmailAvailability aborted

Comment: The OPTIONS HTTP method is invoked when trying to access cross domain resource. Are the HTML page and the web service running out of the  same web server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JSON.stringify on a string value.

```
data: { email: JSON.stringify('test@yopmail.com')},
```

change that to

```
data: { email: 'test@yopmail.com'},
```

And to properly print out what's going on in your error, you need to change the parameters of your error function.  Your first param is the xhr object, you probably want to inspect the second and third params to see what is failing.

> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

From the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i get the same result: Test[object]

Answer (score 0):

Fix typo loca-host and don't concatenate `String` with `Object`:

```
 $('#test_json').click(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/WebServices/Email_Availability/Email_Availability_V1_1.asmx/CheckEmailAvailability",
    data: { email: JSON.stringify('test@yopmail.com')},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

        alert('data');

    },
     error: function(data){ alert(data); }
  });
 });
```